# How to deserialize this xml using List (not array)

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am trying to do deserialization IN SILVERLIGHT using c#. Before i was using XmlArray and it was working but i want to use List instead because 
i have done the previous part all using List (so looks odd when i use array just for it).

My xml is like:

```
<ps>
    <disable_others>
        <disable_other>
            <disable_value>1</disable_value>
            <to_disable>skew</to_disable>
            <to_disable>skew_side</to_disable>
        </disable_other>
        <disable_other>
            <disable_value>0</disable_value>
            <to_disable>automodel</to_disable>
        </disable_other>
    </disable_others>
<ps>
```

And my trY to deserialize it is:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ps")]
    public class ps
    {
      [XmlArray("disable_others")]
      [XmlArrayItem("disable_other", IsNullable = false)]  
      public List<string> Disable_Others { get; set; } 

      /* I know it can be done using the below but i have to use List not array:
              [XmlArray("disable_others")]
        [XmlArrayItem("disable_other", IsNullable = false)]
        public Disable_Other[] Disable_Others { get; set; } */



    }


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "disable_Others")]
    public class Disable_Others
    {
        [XmlElement("disable_other")]
        public List<Disable_Other> Disable_Other { get; set; }

    }

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Disable_Other")]
    public class Disable_Other
    {
        [XmlElement("disablingitem")]
        public int DisablingItem { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("to_disable")]
        public string[] To_Disable { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("disable_value")]
        public byte Disable_Value { get; set; }

    }
```

**Could some one please help me achieving the target using List instead of array(XmlArray) ?**

Comment: If you already have it working for an array, can't you just use [`Enumerable.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the array? (Or is that too inefficient?)

Comment: @MatthewWatson No i have to do it manually.

Comment: u can use xmlarray...with a list field...and u have to mark your classes as [serializable].

Comment: @terrybozzio you mean something like :         [XmlArray("disable_others")]
        [XmlArrayItem("disable_other", IsNullable = false)]
        public List<Disable_Other> Disable_Others { get; set; }

Comment: more like: [XmlArray("disable_others")] [XmlArrayItem(typeof(disable_other), IsNullable = false)] public List<Disable_Other> Disable_Others { get; set; }.

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'disable_other' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) CORRESPONDING TO  :[XmlArrayItem(typeof(disable_other), IsNullable = false)]

Answer (score 2):

Your XML should be formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ps xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <disable_others>
    <Disable_Other>
      <disablingitem>0</disablingitem>
      <to_disable>
        <string>skew</string>
        <string>skew_side</string>
      </to_disable>
      <disable_value>1</disable_value>
    </Disable_Other>
    <Disable_Other>
      <disablingitem>0</disablingitem>
      <to_disable>
        <string>automodel</string>
      </to_disable>
      <disable_value>0</disable_value>
    </Disable_Other>
  </disable_others>
</ps>
```

After this your classes should be the following:

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ps")]
    public class ps
    {
        [XmlArray("disable_others")]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Disable_Other), IsNullable = false)]
        public List<Disable_Other> Disable_Others { get; set; }

        public ps()
        {
            Disable_Others = new List<Disable_Other>();
        }

    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("disable_other")]
    public class Disable_Other
    {
        [XmlElement("disablingitem")]
        public int DisablingItem { get; set; }

        //[XmlElement("to_disable")]
        [XmlArray("to_disable")]
        public string[] To_Disable { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("disable_value")]
        public byte Disable_Value { get; set; }

    }
```

And in your code to deserialize like this:

```
ps p;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ps));
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test1.xml"))
{
    //basic exception handling...
    try
    {
        p = (ps)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
 }
```

Comment: sorry i am not able to acces the "skew" and "skew_side". And why i need to have array to access the data inside Disable_Other[index] ? I am trying t do "object1.Disable_Others[0].To_Disable" ans it show 0 and null for everything inside.

Comment: And is it must to use [Serializable] because before i was not using it and it was working (when iwas working like this public Disable_Other[] Disable_Others { get; set; }) even without [Serializable].

Comment: the way your xml is formatted there are 2 to_disable values,and in your code To_Disable is an array and in xml it should be like in my example,please try it out,make a xml file and paste my example xml,then create the 2 classes as i did and in your calling code place my deserializing example and you will see everything working...